# Add a custom action button in active_admin input form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Iam working on active_admin form. my requirement is to add a button beside a input box to create new project
How to add a action item inside a form ?

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :task
      f.input :project
      f.input :members, :input_html => { :class => "chosen-input" }, :label => 'Assigned To'
      f.actions
    end
 end
```

i want to add a new project button beside input field project

Answer (score 1):

Though it is a very old question, stil i was also looking for the answer, This is how to do it:

just add it after `f.input :project`:

```
f.button "New Project", formaction: "new_entry", class: "some_class"
```

Then using `member_action`:

```
member_action :new_entry, method: :patch do
    
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
inputs 'Details' do
  li do
    label "Project"

    span do
      "here is your project input field"
    end

    span do
      "here is your button"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Consider explaining your answer. Only code may invite unwanted downvotes.